# Setting for add to second user model in Django

Tags: django, authentication, model

I want to add second user model, not to customize built-in model.
(For example, if the built-in model is "Customer",
"Designer" is another model which I would make.)

It's because to allow signup, product publishing of "Designer" themselves.

I've searched how to write second user model, there was to add a second user model through inherits a second user model, but not explained for settings.py.

Should I add additional code such as`AUTH_USER_MODEL = models.Designer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two user models in Django.

Use the built-in `User` model and create "profile" models with `OneToOne` relation to the `User`:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...

class Designer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
```

In this case you can create any number of profile models and access to them from the `User` instance will be as easy as:

```
customer = request.user.customer
designer = request.user.designer
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have been making up a client based on the built-in model, don't created the Customer model you said. If I keep go with current model structure, Is there a problem adding the Designer Model??

Comment: No, there will be no problem.  You can create the `Designer` model with the 1-to-1 field to `Customer`.  The only thing is that `Customer` may have fields which are not needed for `Designer`s.